# call non-static class method with dynamic class name

Tags: class, dynamic, methods

Right now I'm solving the problem like this:

```
    switch($action)
    {
      case "get":

        if("sections" == $table){
          echo $get->nested();
        }

        else {
          echo $get->elements();
        }

      break;

      case "upd":

        if("sections" == $table){
          echo $upd->nested();
        }

        else {
          echo $upd->elements();
        }

      break;
    }
```

But there must be a more 'elegant' way right?!

```
    if("sections" == $table)
      call_user_func(array(ucfirst($action), 'nested'));
    else 
      call_user_func(array(ucfirst($action), 'elements'));
```

is not working. How to solve that?